# Error de conexión Oracle SQL Developer en Mac

Tags: sql, oracle, macos

instale en mi mac Oracle SQL Developer siguiendo una guia [como instalar Oracle en Mac (ingles)](http://mac.thetutorialfree.com/2017/10/11/how-to-oracle-sql-developer-mac-high-sierra-install-easy-guide/)

Instale el Oracle Java Development Kit 8+ y Install Oracle JDK for Mac.
Todo bien hasta que intento establecer una conexion, me da el siguiente error: Estado: Fallo:Fallo de la prueba: Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
[image: ErrorT_T]
Ayuda porfavor!!!

Comment: tus credenciales de acceso: usuario y contraseña si estan correctamente escritos?

Comment: Hola, lo acabo de instalar estoy intentando con el sys o hr para poder configurar los datos pero con ambos me da error

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL Developer es una herramienta "cliente" para conectarse a bases de datos Oracle. En tu pantalla, estás intentando conectarte a tu propio equipo, en donde (asumo) no tienes instalado Oracle Database (no hay una versión para Mac).

Lo que te recomiendo, es que instales una Virtual Machine con Oracle Database preinstalado. La puedes descargar de aquí:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html